# Variance of Mean Response at the Mean of the Data

Tags: variance, forecasting, least-squares

My question concerns the variance of the mean response as outlined
[in this short article](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON4150/v04/seminar/Var_f.pdf) or [in this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_and_predicted_response#Mean_response).
Basically, the variance of the mean response is given by

$$\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} x_0\right)= \sigma^2 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_0 - \bar{x})^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right),$$

where $x_0$ is the data point at which the mean response is predicted.

What I am interested in, however, is a slight modification of this. I would like to compute the variance of the mean response *at the mean of the data*. If I simply use $x_0 = \bar{x}$, the result is straight forward:

$$\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \bar{x}\right)= \sigma^2 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(\bar{x} - \bar{x})^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

But this is not exactly what I am interested in. According to my intuition, since $\bar{x} = \mathrm{E}[x]$ (i.e. $\bar{x}$ is estimated as well), the variance should account for the uncertainty in $\mathrm{E}[x]$. So, I am interested in

$$\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \mathrm{E}[x]\right)$$

Using basic algebra, I arrive at:
$$\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \mathrm{E}[x]\right) = \mathrm{E}\left[\left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \mathrm{E}[x]\right)^2\right] - \mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \mathrm{E}[x]\right]^2
$$
$$ = \mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\alpha}^2\right] - \mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\alpha}\right]^2 +2\mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta}\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]\right] -2\mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\alpha}\right]\mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\beta}\right]\mathrm{E}\left[x\right] + \mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\beta}^2\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]^2\right] -\mathrm{E}\left[\hat{\beta}\right]^2\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]^2
$$
In the case where $x_0$ is not stochastic, this simplifies to variances and covariances of the parameters. $\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha}\right)$ is still present as the first two terms, but how do I continue simplifying the rest of the equation? Or, does anyone know the result (i.e. how to express $\text{Var} \left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} \mathrm{E}[x]\right)$)?

Many thanks for any hint! I am happy to provide further clarification of what I mean if it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If defined, there is no uncertainty of $E[X]$ because it is constant, and doesn't depend on data. It's defined purely by the distribution. That is also why $\bar{x}\neq E[X]$, which contradicts your intuition. Sample mean is calculated from data points. So, since you can treat $E[X]$ as if it is another $x_0$, just substitute into your first equation to obtain the variance of the mean response at that point.

**Edit regarding your comment**:
When $\bar{X}$ is stochastic (i.e. $X_i$ are stochastic), what we have is actually $\operatorname{var}(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}\bar{X}|\bar{X})$, i.e. $\bar{X}$ is known. We'll use [Law of Total Variance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_total_variance) to find unconditional variance. Note also that $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$ are unbiased estimators of the true coefficients.
 $$E[\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}\bar{X}|\bar{X}]=\alpha+\beta\bar{X}$$
Substituting into the law of TV:
$$\operatorname{var}(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}\bar{X})=\operatorname{E\left[\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right]}+\operatorname{var}(\alpha+\beta\bar{X})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\beta^2\sigma_x^2}{n}$$

where $\sigma_x^2$ is the variance of $X_i$.

Comment: Ok, so basically, it is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$?

Comment: No. You'll put $x_0=E[X]$ in the first equation and leave it as it is. You need to convince yourself that $\bar{x}\neq E[X]$ in general, before closing up this issue by the way.

Comment: I now see that $\mathbb{E}(x) \neq \bar{x}$, since the expectation is the true mean of the distribution, while the other is the sample mean. If I use the (estimated) sample mean (which has a variance), does this not change the variance of the mean response at all? Is it just like a constant?

Comment: Normally, sample mean has a variance as you said; but here $x_i$'s are also known  numbers. So is $\bar{x}$. If they were stochastic, they couldn't get out of the variance expression. This is also noted in the short article you provided (3rd line).

Comment: Any hint as to where I would need to look if I do not assume the $x_i$ known? Is there even a way to compute the variance of the forecast if the mean has to be estimated (and hence has a variance)?

Comment: Wow, thanks, that‘s it!!